# R: How do I use setdiff() and match() to subset a dataframe?

Tags: r

In the `map` dataframe, the first column is `chromosome` and the second column is `snp`.

```
> dput(map[1:10,])
structure(list(V1 = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L,
15L, 15L), V2 = c("SNP_A-1850451", "SNP_A-1910129", "SNP_A-1793338",
"SNP_A-1938260", "SNP_A-2269619", "SNP_A-2246474", "SNP_A-2275061",
"SNP_A-1961089", "SNP_A-2131173", "SNP_A-4227303"), V3 = c(0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V4 = c(41361016L, 41366515L,
41386408L, 41396801L, 41410208L, 41419430L, 41440229L, 41446338L,
41449654L, 41455192L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The `mc` dataframe is a subset of `map` based on the `snps` vector.

```
> snps <- c("SNP_A-2240938","SNP_A-2249234","SNP_A-2120212","SNP_A-1864785","SNP_A-1944204","SNP_A-2101022","SNP_A-2192181","SNP_A-4296300","SNP_A-1961028","SNP_A-2215249","SNP_A-2172180","SNP_A-1945117","SNP_A-1941491")
>
> # Subset the map file by the SNPs cis
> mc <- map[map[,2] %in% snps,]
```

Now I want to extract all of the remaining SNPs only on `chromosome` 14. I also want to use `setdiff()` to get the remaining SNPs **that are different** from those in `mc`. Then use these SNP names with the match() function on the original map file.

```
> # Extract all of the remaining SNPs only on chromosome 14
> for (i in 1:nrow(map)) {
+  if (map$V1==14 && setdiff(map,mc)) {
+     t.snp <- map[i,]
+   }
+ }
>
> t.snp
data frame with 0 columns and 10784 rows
```

Problem:
My `t.snp` dataframe has 0 columns.

Comment: `dplyr::filter(map, V1 == 14 & V2 %in% snps)`

Comment: @danlooo I want to get remaining snps on chromosome 14 that are NOT in snps.

Comment: `dplyr::filter(map, V1 == 14 & ! V2 %in% snps)`